# a substantial bandwidth savings - an indefinite article preceding a plural noun

Tags: grammar, articles

> The code used to produce graphics on the client side is typically much smaller than the images themselves, creating **a substantial bandwidth savings**.

Is there any explanation as to why indefinite articles are sometimes used with plural nouns expressing quantities? When do we use them and when don't?

Comment: *Savings* is odd - plural in form, singular in sense.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11395/why-does-american-english-pluralize-certain-singular-nouns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As StoneyB says, here, *savings* seems odd and singular would have made better sense. After all, it's not [*money savings!*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/saving#saving__4) for what we have ***savings*** account in a bank.

It seems that the author has used it as a *collective noun* and thus an indefinite article *a*.